# Подгрузка контента внутри слайдера через скрипт loadmore

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Есть сайт на вордпресс. Нужно сделать подгрузку контента внутри слайда в слайдере. Проблема в том, что скрипты работают нормально, но когда нажимаешь на кнопку "Загрузить ещё" весь контент разворачивается, но прячется по высоте за слайдер. Без скрипта подгрузки контента, слайдер работает с высотой при помощи скрита, ниже укажу код:

```js
$('#link_id_1').click(function() {
        var height = $('#sec1').height();
        $('#slider').css('height', height);
        $("#link_id_1").addClass("active");
        $("#link_id_2").removeClass("active");
    });
    $('#link_id_2').click(function() {
        var height = $('#sec2').height();
        $('#slider').css('height', height);
        $("#link_id_1").removeClass("active");
        $("#link_id_2").addClass("active");
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myList').hide();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
     $('#myList').fadeIn();
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $('#myList').show();
        $('#loadMore').hide();
    });
});


 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#slidorion').slidorion();
 });
```

```css
#header {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#slidorion {
    width: 1140px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -415px;
}

.klientslid {
    margin-left: -418px !important;
}

#slider {
    width: 751px;
    height: 575px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slidklient {
    width: 810px !important;
}

.slider-image {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
<div id="slidorion" class="klientslid">
<div id="slider" class="slidklient">
<div id="sec1" class="slider-image" rel="section1">
<div class="sodv">
Контент
</div>
<div id="myList">
<div class="sodv">
контент дополнительный
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="loadMore"><a style="cursor:  pointer;" class="podrobnee2">Загрузить ещё</a></div> 
</div>
<div id="sec2" class="slider-image" rel="section2">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="accordion" class="accklienti">
<div class="header"><a id="link_id_1" class="slider-link" rel="section1">Все</a></div>
<div class="header"><a id="link_id_2" class="slider-link" rel="section2">Транспорт</a></div>
</div>
 </div>
 <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Проблема в том, что все работает нормально. "  )))

Comment: @KAGGDesign я имел ввиду скрипты ))